# Get the users who are having server access for my server

Tags: powershell

We need to extract a report every month for our servers which should report who all are having the server admin access .This will help us remove the people for whom access is no more needed.  Its taking lot of time to extract manually and I read on blogs that PowerShell is used to automate such kind of administration jobs.

Other details: 
Server - Win 2008 R2
Powershell 1.0
Could any one help me how to I extract this report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for ADSI and PSRemoting. Example:

```
$cComputerNames = @("computer1", "computer2")
$cRows = @()

foreach ($sComputerName in $cComputerNames) {
    $cAdminAccounts = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $sComputerName `
        -Class "Win32_GroupUser" `
        | Where-Object { 
            ($_.GroupComponent -split '"')[3] -eq "Administrators" 
          }
    foreach ($cAdminAccount in $cAdminAccounts) {
        $oRow = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
            "ComputerName"  = $sComputerName
            "AccountDomain" = ($cAdminAccount.PartComponent -split '"')[1]
            "AccountName"   = ($cAdminAccount.PartComponent -split '"')[3]
        }
        $cRows += $oRow
    }
}

$cRows | Export-Csv -Path "admin-accounts.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

You can use an `associators of ...` query to get more detailed info about accounts. See [this blog post](http://jdhitsolutions.com/blog/wmi/2338/query-local-administrators-with-wmi/).

Comment: Thanks for the solution.. I have tried on SOme other server with Powershell 3.0 in it and it worked :) Can I save the result into CSV?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick way to enumerate the list of administrators for a server.

```psh
$group = [ADSI]"WinNT://./Administrators"

@($group.Invoke("Members")) | foreach {
  $_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)
}
```

You can then use an email cmdlet to send it or however you want to send it back to you.

See: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/10/27/the-admin-s-first-steps-local-group-membership.aspx

Comment: The best way might be to run the above remotely via `Invoke-Command` (provided PSRemoting is enabled on the target computers, that is).

Comment: Hi Jason.  Thanks for your response. We are using the powershell 1.0 in our server and when I tried the first statement                         "distinguishedName
-----------------"          is the result for me and when I tried complete script below is the error message  "Exception calling "Invoke" with "1" argument(s): "Member not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020003 (DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND))"
At line:1 char:16
+ @($group.Invoke( <<<< "Members")) | foreach {   $_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)}" Do you have any idea on this?